# Is the Google Strategy in Passport.js deprecated with the end of Google+

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-plus, google-signin

I use Passport.js and passport-google-oauth20 in my nodejs aplication for authenticating with a "Google Strategy".
I just received an email from Google indicating that I use "plus.people.get" from the Google+ API and that it will be deprecated.
Should I change something? I do not use directly this API call but maybe Passport does?

Comment: Investigating this right now as well. Seems like it is really calling https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me to get the user profile. Will track and update this question as soon as I find out if it switches automatically (seem it can do this) or we need to change something. So far voting up for this issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes the Google OAuth strategy for Passport currently uses the Google+ API endpoints for retrieving the user's profile information.

If you disable the Google+ API integration from Google console on https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard then the sign-in with Google will not work for your application. The error received back from Google contains this message:

> GooglePlusAPIError: Access Not Configured. Google+ API has not been used in project xxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/plus.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

In order for your application to work properly having Google+ API disabled, you have to use this strategy option:

```
userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo'
```

like in this example:

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback",
    userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
           ...
  }
));
```

Comment: We are facing this issue with our app as well. We were considering moving to the people API, would the oAuth 2.0 strategy work for that?

Comment: Lifesaver! This solution also works for ```passport-google-oauth```

Comment: You can find the mappings to the scopes at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide