# NodeJS passport How to migrate project from Google+ sign in to Google sign In?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth

Few days back, I had received a message from google that they are removing their Google+ Api's. Is there any way I can migrate the project using passportJS. What are the required steps?

Comment: It is not necessary to migrate your existing data, you could just use a different `userProfileURL` as I mention here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54112673/1312107

Answer (score 0):

Passport has support for [Google](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/), which is just an oauth provider. If [this](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) is what you've been using, then the transition should be *decent*, cause the Google+ Platform Login seems to be an oauth provider as well. So at best you'd be looking at switching some keys and some URLs.

See their [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide) for tips about migrating from one to the other.

You might need to do a data migration as well at some point - would ids for users from one platform carry over to the other platform? You need to look into this as well.

Comment: Which Api will we have to select in google developers console?

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to enable a special API, like you would for Geocoding in Maps or Kubernetes in GCP. You do need to get credentials like [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) though.